Sending mail fails with no exception
I use the following code to send email:
public static void SendMail(string emailAddresses, string subject, string body, bool isHtml)
{
    var currentSecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;

    try
    {
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient(MailServer))
        {
            /*
             * Define the credentials to use the SMTP server
             * and security protocol
             */
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MailUser, MailPassword);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // MailSecurityProtocol;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Port = MailPort;

            /*
             * Sends the email message
             */
            using (var email = new MailMessage())
            {
                email.From = 
                email.Sender = new MailAddress(MailFrom);
                email.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(MailFrom));
                
                var Combined_Addresses = emailAddresses; 
                var addrs = Combined_Addresses.Split(';');
                foreach (var addr in addrs)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(addr))
                        continue;
                    email.To.Add(addr);
                }

                email.Subject = subject;
                email.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
                email.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                if (body.Length != 0)
                {
                    email.Body = body;
                    email.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                }
                smtp.Send(email);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Extensions.LogException(null, ex);
    }
    finally
    {
       ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = currentSecurityProtocol;
    }
}

The code executes without throwing any exception, but the mail is not sent.
If I try sending to an invalid address, it bounces.
So, I believe it is some problem at the SMTP, but I have no idea what.
Any clue would be appreciated.

It's a proprietary mail server.
But I found a configuration of user/server/port that allowed me to sent emails.
